# board with webserver, email, snmp

Tags: embedded, hardware, webserver, snmp

I am looking for board, module, kit for our new project.

requierments:

necessary:

- IP interface IPv4/IPv6
- DHCP, StaticIp, ICMP(Ping)
- SNMP V2, V3
- HTTP, Webserver
- Email

good to have:

- Telnet
- SSH
- SysLog

There are two ways:

1. complete controlled modul + master(some 8-bit with rs232, spi, ..) 
   I've found this http://www.connectone.com/products.asp?did=73&pid=92
   But there is probably problem with SMTP, it isnt direct supported. Only UDP.
2. some board with linux

Thanks for your advices and recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this XPORT PRO from LANTRONIX.

http://www.lantronix.com/device-networking/embedded-device-servers/xport-pro.html

There is Linux, so all 'net' stuffs should be supported.
8MB SDRAM/16MB Flash
small, cheap

Do you have some experience with that?

The second tip is http://www.rabbit.com/
Very powerfull modules with C libraries.

Answer (score 0):

with such heavy requirements, i would definitely go for an embedded computer running linux or a lighter unix based kernel. it will give you some flexibility over the software package, and you will easily find some support.

(there are plenty of embedded computers on the market, i can't chose one...)